# Bootstrap: mixing independent and time-series data together

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, bootstrap, simulation, convergence

I have a very computationally heavy simulator (large-scale agent-based transport simulation), which usually takes up to 5 days of run time in a large computer. The results are probabilistic, so multiple runs are required to build confidence intervals.

Since this is so heavy, I was thinking of using bootstrap to reduce the number of runs needed by sampling from different iterations.

Basically the idea is to make up a sample of 10 iterations (possibly with a lag to reduce auto-correlation issues) of each of 10 independent runs. The sampled iterations are after stationarity has been reached.

The total sample of 100 would be then composed of 10 time-series (of the iterations) from 10 different runs.

If I could assume no auto-correlation, then all samples are representative and I can do a normal bootstrap for calculating my CIs. 
If on the other hand I'd use only iterations from a single run, then a time-series bootstrap would work, but in this case I'd like to mix both kinds of data because one single run isn't always representative.

Do you know if this could work and how I should proceed to properly do this?

The intended application is scenario comparison, so hypothesis testing with e.g. link volumes to see what changes and how much.